# Get top border of image to align with text using only `\includegraphics` from `graphicx`

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

Bu using the default positioning of an image inserted with `\includegraphics`, from the `graphicx` package, an image following some text (not a new line) is aligned in such a way that it sticks out from the top, and the bottom of the text line is aligned with the image's bottom border, as you can see in the image below:

[image: image aligned inconveniently]

I would rather like the image to stick out from the bottom, in such a way that the top of the text line (in this case, "**Question #2**") be aligned with the top border of the image.

How do I achieve this effect using only the `graphicx` package and `\includegraphics` command, and nothing else, if possible? Excuse me for this imposed limitation. This is for homework, and I don't have the time to wrap my head around something like TikZ for now.

Here's a MWE, where I just stripped everything from my document but **Question #2** and the command definitions and packages required to make it compile successfully (look at the line that starts with `\includegraphics` under the "body" header):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top = 0.5in, bottom = 1in, left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in]{geometry}

% ===== for math =====
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\mtangent}{m_\text{tangent}}
\newcommand{\msecant}{m_\text{secant}}
\newcommand{\Given}{\textbf{Given:}~}
\newcommand{\Required}{\textbf{Required:}~}
\newcommand{\Analysis}{\textbf{Analysis:}~}
\newcommand{\Solution}{\textbf{Solution:}~}
\newcommand{\Statement}{\textbf{Statement:}~}
\newcommand{\idem}{\emph{idem}}
\newcommand{\UNDEF}{\text{UNDEF}}
\newcommand{\DNE}{~\text{DNE}}

% ===== for question numbering =====
\usepackage{enumitem}

% ===== for graphics, including images and plots =====
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

% ===== body =====
\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Question \#\arabic*}, align=left, leftmargin=*]
  \refstepcounter{enumi}
  \item % Question #2
  \includegraphics[width=7cm]{question2.pdf}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]\item{ % (a)
  \Given graph\\
  \Required \( \lim\limits_{x\to3^-}{f(x)} \)\\
  \Statement \( \lim\limits_{x\to3^-}{f(x)} = 1 \)
  }
  \item{ % (b)
  \Given\idem\\
  \Required \( \lim\limits_{x\to3^+}{f(x)} \)\\
  \Statement \( \lim\limits_{x\to3^+}{f(x)} = -2 \)
  }
  \item{ % (c)
  \Given\idem\\
  \Required \( \lim\limits_{x\to3}{f(x)} \)\\
  \Analysis\\
  \( \lim\limits_{x\to3^-}{f(x)}\neq\lim\limits_{x\to3^+}{f(x)} \)\\
  \( \therefore\lim\limits_{x\to3}{f(x)}\DNE \)\\
  \Statement\( \lim\limits_{x\to3}{f(x)}\DNE \)
  }\end{enumerate} % end alpha
 \end{enumerate} % end question numbering
 
\end{document}
```

Here's [question2.pdf](https://www.mediafire.com/file/6kll74t3cylv9di/question2.pdf/file), for testing purposes.

Comment: Use \raisebox to move the picture down. Or use the adjustbox package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment! Can you show me a small sample of code so I can see how that `\raisebox` function works in my context? Thank you again.

Comment: sure, it you provide some small sample of code (a "Minimal Working Example", MWE) that I can use to insert and test my code. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343/2388 https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to include a MWE.

Comment: I can't compile that as I don't have question2.pdf. Please test such a example in a new, empty folder to avoid to have local dependencies.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I apologise for the inconvenience. I hate wasting people's time. I've linked `question2.pdf` in my question, so you can download that and place it in an `image` folder where your test document is. My apologies again, and thank you for taking the time to help me out with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}[start=2,label=\textbf{Question \#\arabic*}, align=left, leftmargin=*]
  \item % Question #2
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image}}
  
  more text
 \end{enumerate} 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solves it perfectly. I appreciate it greatly, and I wish you a great day. Thanks for your time.